# How to get my validated JavaScript data into a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

To my understanding since JavaScript is a browser-side language and MySQL is server side, I need a server-side language that can interact with the browser such as PHP. I've been looking for solutions here and on the web but to no luck.

My question is -- with the code below is there general format on how  can send validated information through the PHP to get to a database?

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="regForm" onSubmit="return validateRegForm();">

<table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table align="center" bordercolor="white" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2"><strong>Registration</strong></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><br></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">E-mail:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder=" email"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Username:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="text" name="username" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder=" username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Password:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="password" name="password" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder=" password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Confirm Password:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="password" name="cpassword" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder=" confirm password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">First Name:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder=" first name"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Last Name:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder=" last name"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Team Name:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="text" name="teamname" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder=" team name"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input class="bigButton" type="submit" value="Register"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateRegForm()
{   
    //Validates email address
    var a = document.forms["regForm"]["email"].value;
    if (a == null || a == "") {
        alert("You forgot to enter your Email!");
        return false;
    } else {
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if (a.match(mailformat)) {
            document.regForm.email.focus();
        } else {
            alert("You have entered an invalid Email Address!");
            document.regForm.email.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    //Validates username
    var aa = document.forms["regForm"]["username"].value;
        if (aa == null || aa == "") {
            alert("You forgot to enter your Username!");
            document.regForm.username.focus();
            return false;
    }
    re = /^\w+$/;
        if (!re.test(regForm.username.value)) {
            alert("Your Username must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores!");
            document.regForm.username.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (aa.length < 7) {
            alert("Your Username is too short! (8 character min)");
            document.regForm.username.focus();
            return false;
        }
    //Validates password & confirm password
    if (regForm.password.value != "" && regForm.password.value == regForm.cpassword.value) {
        if (regForm.password.value.length < 7) {
            alert("Your Password must contain at least 8 characters!");
            document.regForm.email.focus();
            return false;
        }
    re = /[0-9]/;
    if(!re.test(regForm.password.value)) {
        alert("Your Password must contain at least one number (0-9)!");
        document.regForm.password.focus();
        return false;
      }
    re = /[a-z]/;
    if(!re.test(regForm.password.value)) {
        alert("Your Password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!");
        document.regForm.password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    re = /[A-Z]/;
    if(!re.test(regForm.password.value)) {
        alert("Your Password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!");
        document.regForm.password.focus();
        return false; }
    } else {
        alert("Please check that you've entered or confirmed your password!");
        document.regForm.password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    //Validates first name
    var b = document.forms["regForm"]["firstname"].value;
        if (b == null || b == "") {
            alert('You forgot to enter your First Name!');
            return false;
        }
    //Validates last name
    var c = document.forms["regForm"]["lastname"].value;
        if (c == null || c == "") {
            alert('You forgot to enter your Last Name!');
            return false;
        }
    //Validates team name
    var d = document.forms["regForm"]["teamname"].value;
        if (d == null || d == "") {
            alert('You forgot to enter your Team Name!');
            document.regForm.teamname.focus();
            return false;
    }
    re = /^\w+$/;
        if (!re.test(regForm.teamname.value)) {
            alert("Team Name must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores!");
            document.regForm.teamname.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (d.length < 7) {
            alert("Your Team Name is too short! (8 character min)");
            document.regForm.teamname.focus();
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I could not get jsfiddle to work - got some type of 'code must be accompanied error', I apologize in advance.

Comment: $_POST[key] will have the information contained within each field, so $_POST['name'] would be the name textbox.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: I would advise against reliance on client-side validation (although it is still a helpful layer before sending data to the server side).  As for PHP "interacting" with the browser, once PHP is done, it is done....until the next request at least.  If you need to have interaction between client and server within a webpage without having to completely reload the page, you may wish to look into [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming).

Comment: Make sure to set the action tag to be the path to PHP file that will process the form's $_POST data.  See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of approaches to your problem.
This one is what I think,

```
<form method="post" name="regForm" onSubmit="return validateRegForm();">
```

This part should have an 'action'.

On your form, there should be an

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

This will invoke that "onSubmit" action in your "form" tag.

Try this out. Maybe these are the things you're missing out.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Client-side validation has a different role than that of the server. While the server's job is to keep out [bad guys](http://bobby-tables.com/) and make sure your data is clean, client-side validation should have the purpose of making the filling out of forms as least annoying as possible.

Doing good server-side validation is a science in itself. Fortunately, there are frameworks that make it easier to do it properly ([Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/validation) and [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) are personal favorites), but if you have the commendable aim of learning to do it from scratch, there's plenty out there to read.

Good client-side validation takes advantage of JavaScript's strengths. It's instant and shows the user exactly where the problem is. You've got that down for the most part, except for the fact that the user gets one error at a time and has to click through alerts until they've got it right. There's also some repetition we can get rid of.

We can gather your validation into an array of objects with a name and a regular expression.

```
var validators = [
  {name: 'username', test: /^[\d\w]{8,}$/},
  {name: 'email', test: /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/},
  {name: 'password', test: /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/},
  {name: 'cpassword', test: /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/},
  {name: 'firstname', test: /w+/},
  {name: 'lastname', test: /w+/},
  {name: 'teamname', test: /[\w+\d+]{8,}/}
```

];

Next, let's get rid of the alerts and put red error messages right next to their fields. First, the CSS for that:

```
td.hide{
  display: none;
}
td.error {
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #F00;
  padding: 0 0 0 30%;
}
```

...and in our table, we'll add hidden rows with the error messages already in them, [like  so](http://codepen.io/chadh/pen/gHBnt/). You could get sophisticated and taylor the message to the type of error by modifying the validators array above with custom messages and then coding for it below, but for simplicity I'm going to leave it as one regex per field and hardcode the error into the hidden validation rows. You could also add ajax calls to the server checking whether usernames/emails are already taken, but this should be a good start.

Now we can make one function that iterates through the array whenever the user changes something. This doesn't cost a whole lot and is practically instant.

```
function validateRegForm(event)
{
  var formIsValid = true;
  for(var i=0; i < validators.length; i++){
      var currentField = document.getElementsByName(validators[i].name)[0];
      var validationField = document.getElementById(validators[i].name + "Validation");
      //check that this field is valid, as well as the other filled out ones along the way
      if(validators[i].name == event.target.name || currentField.value.length > 0){
          if(validators[i].test.test(currentField.value)){
            validationField.setAttribute("class", "hide");
          }else{
            validationField.setAttribute("class", "error");
            formIsValid = false;
          }
          //do the passwords match?
          if(currentField.name == 'cpassword' || validators[i].name == 'cpassword'){
            if(document.getElementsByName('cpassword')[0].value != document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value){
                document.getElementById('cpasswordValidation').setAttribute("class", "error");
                formIsValid = false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('cpasswordValidation').setAttribute("class", "hide");
            }
         }
      }
  }
  if(!formIsValid){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  return formIsValid;
}
```

Going over the script, we are first assuming the form is valid with `var formIsValid`. As soon as we hit something that isn't, we change it to false so that at the end, the form doesn't submit. Then we just iterate through and see what's valid. We ignore empty fields unless it's the one the user just changed, so that the user doesn't start with their email and then get red everywhere because it's all blank. Finally, we put in a special condition to compare passwords.

See my [Codepen](http://codepen.io/chadh/pen/gHBnt/) to see it in action.

On the server, you should check for the same things as above and then properly escape & encode it for storage in the database. You should not assume that the form was posted from your registration page. There are ways to check that on the server and reject the user if the request didn't come from your page. Most server-side languages have built-in ways to do this stuff, but a good framework will make it less of a headache.